# Record-doubling problem on a simple left join

Tags: mysql, join

I'm running this query:

```
CREATE TABLE
SELECT people.*, Sheet1.department
  FROM people LEFT JOIN Sheet1 ON people.depno = Sheet1.depno
```

On a set of tables detailing employee records.

**The goal** is to create a new table that has all the "people" data, plus a human-readable department name. Simple, right?

**The problem** is that each record in the resulting table appears to be duplicated exactly (with literally every field being the same), turning a roughly 23,000-record table into a roughly 46,000-record table. I say "roughly" because it's not an exact doubling -- there's a difference of about a hundred records.

Some details: The "people" table contains 15 fields, including the "depno" field, which is an integer indicating department.

The "Sheet1" table is, as one would guess, a table generated from an imported xls file containing two fields: the shared "depno" and a new "department" (the latter being a verbose department name corresponding to the depno in question). There are 44 records in the "Sheet1" table.

Thanks in advance for any pointers on this. Let me know what other information you can use from me.

---

Update: Here's the code I ended up using, from my response to Johan (thanks again to everyone who worked on this):

```
CREATE TABLE morebetter 
    SELECT people.*, Sheet1.department FROM people 
    LEFT JOIN Sheet1 ON people.depno = Sheet1.depno 
    GROUP BY id
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6151157/good-mysql-tutorials/

Comment: Is `depno` unique in the Sheet1 table?  Sounds like you might have duplicates.

Comment: Thanks, guys. I'll take a look at those. (Steve: Sorry, I didn't see your answer before Daren's -- see my response to him.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The people.depno is not unique, that's why you're getting the doubling.

Change the `SELECT` part to

```
SELECT DISTINCT people.*, Sheet1.department
  FROM people LEFT JOIN Sheet1 ON people.depno = Sheet1.depno
```

This will eliminate duplicate rows.

In MySQL you can also write

```
SELECT people.*, Sheet1.department
FROM people LEFT JOIN Sheet1 ON people.depno = Sheet1.depno
GROUP BY people.depno
```

Which works slightly different.
The first query eliminates rows with duplicate **output**, the second query eliminates records with duplicate `people.depno`, even if people.depno does not appear in the output.

I like the second form, because it makes explicit which duplicate you're trying to eliminate and you don't need to tweak the output.
It's also slightly faster in executing time.

*****Warning*****
The `group by` version will eliminate any double people.depno it finds, but if the other fields in the select are not identical it will just choose one at random!
In other words. If the outcome of the `select distinct` is different from the `group by` version that means that MySQL is silently dropping non-duplicate rows.
This may or may not be what you want!

In order to be safe, do a `group by` on **all** fields that you care about!
If the group by is on a `unique` key than it's pointless to include further fields from the same table as that unique key.

Comment: Johan, a combination of your two approaches was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a bunch! (Here's the final query for reference - advance apologies if my attempt at mini-Markdown fails):

`code`
CREATE TABLE morebetter
 SELECT people.*, Sheet1.department
   FROM people LEFT JOIN Sheet1 ON people.depno = Sheet1.depno
   GROUP BY id, people.uid, fy, title
`code`

Hopefully your answer helps someone else in the future when it appears that MySQL is doubling records in query results. It certainly helped me.

Comment: @user490581: MySQL is not doubling any records, unless your data or your query says so. Can you please post the result of this query?: `SELECT COUNT(*), COUNT(DISTINCT depno) FROM Sheet1`

Comment: Nice work. Just when I think I'm certain about something, everybody turns out to be right in their basic initial question. I re-examined the Sheet1 contents, and while the depno fields are unique in the original spreadsheet, some sort of import problem must have indeed caused them to be repeated in the MySQL version. Thanks for the continued skepticism, ypercube: Along with a band-aid, I now have the situation's origin.

(And, since I wouldn't want to deny you a response to your initial question, the query results are 86 and 42 for count(*) and count(distinct depno), respectively.)

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the `Sheet1.depno` field isn't unique?

Comment: Good question, Daren. Sheet1.depno is unique within the "Sheet1" table's records, but you're right: It's not unique within the "people" table's records.

Comment: Whoops -- I was 100% wrong on this. See my response to ypercube. Consider this my tasty crow dinner.